# Uncertainty principle and measurement of the mass of Virtual particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, virtual-particles

1. We can have real photons as well as virtual photons. However, I think we can have only virtual weak gauge bosons $W^{\pm},Z$. Is that correct?
2. If virtual particles are just a manner of interpreting the S-matrix elements at various orders, why something as physical as energy-time uncertainty principle is invoked to explain their fleeting existence? The mathematics of quantum field theory, as far as I know, doesn't give any such picture to take seriously.
3. Since, the virtual particles do not obey dispersion relations, how justified is the measurement of Z-boson mass using the four-momentum conservation as explained in the [maximum voted answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/74099/) here?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform W or Z boson always appear in the propagator such as in the $e^+e^-\rightarrow \mu^+\mu^-$ scattering. Aren't they? And their masses are measured from such scattering events. Am I wrong?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform- What do you think about the measurement of Z boson as answered in the link I have suggested? It appears to me that it assumes dispersion relation to be valid for the Virtual Z boson.

Comment: General comment: Since voting can at least in principle change the order of answers, it is preferred not to refer to SE answers by their popularity.

Comment: I think virtual refers to how closely a particle adheres to the mass-shell relation, i.e the longer it exists, the more it will tend to obey this relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There are both virtual and real $W^{\pm}$, $Z$ bosons. Just as with photons (and for any other case), virtual $W^\pm$ and $Z$ bosons are some internal lines on Feynman diagrams and real $W^\pm$ and $Z$ bosons are some states of the electroweak theory.
2. The time-energy uncertainty principle is a specially tricky version of the uncertainty principle (see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/53802/what-is-delta-t-in-the-time-energy-uncertainty-principle), for example). Some people might use it to give intuition about virtual particles. This kind of analogies are not to be taken too seriously.
3. The $Z$ boson mass was measured at LEP using electron-positron collisions. The cross section for the process that was used can be computed as a function of the center of mass energy $E$ of the final (or, equivalently, the initial) state. Around $E\sim M_Z$ this function has a bell shape peaked at $E=M_Z$ (in this kind of processes, the cross section is a [Breit-Wigner distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Breit%E2%80%93Wigner_distribution)). By measuring many events at different $E$, the peak of the cross section can be found and the mass of the $Z$ boson is obtained.